# How can a finite field have a cardinality that is not prime if every nonzero element is a unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, totient-function

If a field requires every element that is not the additive inverse to have a multiplicative inverse, then how can a field have a cardinality that is not prime?
For instance 27?

So whether it is integers mod 27, or some direct product, there will be a nonzero zero divisor, hence not a unit.  Does that not disqualify it from being a field?

Comment: A better question would seem to be *why do you think there is a problem*? You can write down explicitly a field of order $4 = 2^2$, for example. I think you're probably mixing up the additive structure and the multiplicative structure.

Comment: As you know, the integers modulo $3$ are a $3$-element field. Probably you are thinking that a $27$-element field would have to be the integers modulo $27,$ but as you know the integers modulo $27$ are not a field. There is a $27$-element field, but it is not the integers modulo $27;$ it is an algebraic extension of the $3$-element field.

Comment: @user296602 wouldn't 2 (in one case and (1,0) in another) be a zero divisor and therefore disqualify 4 as a possible cardinality?

Comment: It seems that you're assuming the field is the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, or $\mathbb{Z}_4$. That's not correct.

Comment: @user3146 bof already said this for $27$. The field with $4$ elements is *not* the integers modulo $4$. It is a field which *contains* the field with $2$ elements as a subfield.

Comment: @bof Wouldn't all the possibilities (up to isomorphism) for a 27-element field be Z_27, Z_3 x Z_9, Z_3 x Z_3 x Z_3?

Comment: @user3146 The field of order $4$ is obtained by adjoining to the $2$-element field an "imaginary" root $\alpha$ of the polynomial $x^2+x+1.$ The elements are $0,1,\alpha,1+\alpha;$ addition is modulo $2,$ and $\alpha^2=1+\alpha,\ \alpha^3=1.$

Comment: The field with $27$ elements is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_3^3$ as a *vector space* over $\Bbb F_3$, but not as a ring. Those do not classify the $27$-elements rings. In particular, $\Bbb F_3[x]/(x^3-x-1)$ is a field with $3^3$ elements.

Comment: @user296602 oh, thanks!

Comment: Okay, I think the book I'm working out of went well out of scope for a certain question.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @anon Thanks for the example! and for it having 27 elements

Comment: @bof Is that to say $F_{3}[x]/(x^3-x-1)$? And, can you tell me what "adjoining" means (in general)?

Comment: @user3146 That's fine, because $x^3-x-1$ is an irreducible cubic polynomial over $F_3;$ any irreducible cubic will give you the same (i.e. an isomorphic) $27$-element field. The elements are $a+b\theta+c\theta^2$ where $a,b,c\in F_3;$ addition mod $3,$ as the coefficients are in $F_3;$ when multiplying use $\theta^3=1+\theta$ to reduce higher powers of $\theta.$ As a non-algebraist (or amateur algebraist) I think of it informally; it's analogous to how you get the complex numbers by adjoining the imaginary $i$ (root of the irreducible polynomial $x^2+1$) to the real numbers.

Comment: @bof Sorry. Typo.  I meant to say "$F_{2}/(x^3-x-1)$".

Comment: $F_2$ is the $2$ -element field, it has no quotients to speak of. $F_2[x]$ is the ring of polynomials in $x$ over $F_2.$ The $4$-element field is $F_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ since $x^2+x+1$ is a (the only) irreducible quadratic polynomial over $F_2.$ The $8$-element field is $F_2[x]/p(x)$ where $p(x)$ is any irreducible cubic polynomial over $F_2,$ for example $p(x)=x^3-x-1,$ which is the same as $x^3+x+1;$ alternatively you can get the same field using $x^3+x^2+1.$

Comment: @bof Wow.  I must be tired. Sorry.  I made another typo. "$F_{2}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$" is what I meant to type (both times).  anon's comment is somehow impacting what I type.

Comment: [All about asking questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking), See also: [How to Ask a Homework (or homework-like aka PSQ) Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument shows that any field **that is a quotient of the ring of integers** must have a prime number of elements.  Another way of saying this is that any finite field that has a single additive generator must have a prime number of elements, or more generally that the additive order of any individual nonzero element is prime.

However, not all finite fields are necessarily additively generated by a single element.  The smallest example is $\Bbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$, which has four elements.  Here every element has order 2, and the additive group is the Klein Four group $\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z_2$.  The multiplicative group of units is cyclic of order 3 in this case.

Comment: Great example!  Simple and easy to work out in my head.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Take the matrix
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and take the ring of all
$$  xI + y A + z A^2 $$
with $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z$

This is a field as $x^3 - x - 1$ is irreducible in the base field.

Comment: I'm impressed that you came up with this example so quickly, and thanks for making it 27-element!